# I have a Dell Axim X5 version A05. What's the latest version of Windows Mobile I can update it to?

Tags: windows-ce, pda

Found an old PDA I bought in my garage many years ago, and it looks to be the base model of the Dell Axim X5. I was wondering if it is possible to update the PDA to the latest version of Windows Mobile, 6.5.5.  How do I find out the current version, and what's the latest working OS I can upgrade it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest version Windows Mobile 2003 (Dell ROM version A05), and that is about it... This device was never big with developers like the x50/51 series, so there are no aftermarket ROMs I am aware of.